# AutoHotKey: Trigger infinite loop of keyboard button press when pressing another keyboard button

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make a process automatic, until I require it to stop.

> I press a button on my keyboard, for example F2. 
>   When F2 pressed, it starts a loop that presses F9 every second or so. 
>   This keeps on going until I press F2 again.

I have watched tutorials but all people ever really cover is the mouseclicks. Also the help/tutorialpages from autohotkey itself are very bombastic.
This should be very simple and yet it is not.

```
F2::

SetTimer TheLoop, 200
Return

TheLoop:
Send {F9}

Return
```

Anyone that can help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a variable as a toggle as to whether the timer is run or turned off. Something like:

```
F2::
bToggle := !bToggle
If bToggle
    SetTimer , TheLoop , 200 ; This is 200 ms
Else
    SetTimer , TheLoop , Off
Return

TheLoop:
Send , {F9}
Return
```

Here's a more condensed version using the ternary operator and evaluated expressions:

```
f2::SetTimer , TheLoop , % (( bToggle := !bToggle ) ? "200" : "Off" )

TheLoop:
Send , {f9}
Return
```

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I wanted. No idea why I need a variable when I already say to the F2 key what it has to do.

Comment: @Dokme No problem. The variable alters what the F2 key does. The first time it turns the timer on, the second time it turns it off, repeat. Without the toggle, it just turns it on every time.

Comment: I have tried this function on my browser and it works. I have then tried it in an application, not browserrelated, just a windowsapplication and there it wont work. Any idea why this is a thing? @Evan

Comment: @Dokme Some applications (mainly games) don't work well with SendInput, so you may want to try SendEvent or SendPlay. It's hard to know without having the actual application you're using it on.